# Jquery Select All / Deselect CheckBoxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

I currently have this showing a list of records, I have a few buttons underneath. Two of which are called "Select All" and "Clear All" aimed at the checkboxes. I was wondering how I could implement the code to select all checkboxes present and unselect them sort of like a toggle but on two separate buttons.

```
function showAll(qstring,qtype){
 $("#vsdiv").show();
 var myurl="scripts/searchadmin.php"; 
 $.ajax({
  url: myurl, dataType:'json',data:{querystring:qstring,querytype:qtype},
  success: function(member){
   $("#resultstable").append('<tr class="yellow">'+
                                        '<th>#REC</th><th>JOINED</th><th>USER NAME</th>'+
                                        '<th>CONTACT</th><th>ADDRESS</th><th>PHONE</th>'+
                                        '<th>EMAIL</th><th>STATUS</th><th>SELECT</th></tr>');
   var j=0;var totrecs=1;
   for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    $("#resultstable").append('<tr class="trow'+j+'">'+
                  '<td class="ids" id="z'+i+'">'+totrecs+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+member[i].jdate+'</td>'+
          '<td class="users"     id="username'+i+'">'+member[i].username+'</td>'+
          '<td id="contact'+i+'">'+member[i].fname+' '+member[i].lname+'</td>'+
          '<td id="myaddress'+i+'">'+member[i].address1+' '+member[i].town+'</td>'+
          '<td id="phone'+i+'">'+member[i].phone+'</td>'+
          '<td id="email'+i+'">'+member[i].email+'</td>'+
          '<td id="status'+i+'">'+member[i].status+'</td>'+
          '<td><input type="checkbox" name="whome" id="showMe'+i+'"'+
                                         'class="boxes" onclick="getMe('+i+')" /></td></tr>');  
                                         $('#sr').html('Showing 1 of '+member.length+' Members')

});


  totrecs++;
  j++;
 }
}
});
}
```

Any ideas on the approach I should take is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
$('#selectall').click(
    function() {
        $('.boxes').prop('checked', true);
    }
);
});

$(function () {
$('#clearall').click(
    function() {
        $('.boxes').prop('checked', false);
        }
     );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#selectall').click(function() {
     $('.boxes').attr('checked','checked');
  });
  $('#clearall').click(function() {
    $('.boxes').removeAttr('checked');
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PGRNT/)